# My local git repo doesn't seem to register local changes anymore

Tags: git

I've got a project that I've been working on for a few years. Git has always worked as expected. Recently I started a migration to a new server (Siteground). I set up and cloned my repo (held on Assembla) there and after a bit of tweaking got it working. I made a few changes to some files on my local copy and pushed them to the repo, and then pulled them on the server. It also worked.

Yesterday I made a change to my local copy, commited it and tried to push. But I got an error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.assembla.com:projectname.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Odd. I hadn't made any other changes to stage. So I had a look `git status` and git told me there were a couple of modified files that I hadn't modified in maybe 6 months. I took a look at them made some changes to them and then changed my mind and did `git stash`.

Then I reread the message and realised that the problem was on the repo, not locally. So I did a `git fetch` as I was unsure what all the changes were about, since I normally don't commit and push from the remote server.

To have a look at what the changes were, I did:

```
git log HEAD..origin
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD..origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Err. Really? After some more poking and checking (am I on the right branch and in the right directory, do I exist) I eventually ran `git log -p`. And it showed some small CSS changes I had made eons ago. Weird.

But on the whole they looked like acceptable small changes. So I did a `git pull origin master`. That resulted in 800+ lines of changes. Unexpected. A large part of these were file permission changes of the sort:

```
mode change 100755 => 100644
```

and

```
create mode 100755
```

I thought that was probably due to the new server set up that assigned its own permissions. Weird though that they got committed and pushed to the repo. Maybe I did it by mistake when switching tabs in my terminal. Whatever. Now let's see if I can `git push origin master` with my original changes. But `Everything up-to-date`. I checked if I was on the correct branch and `git status` told me the same thing. I made some test modifications to the file I was originally trying to push. GitX would see the changes and I'd commit throught that. But git in the terminal wouldn't acknowledge the commits.

I double checked if my origins were synced:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@git.assembla.com:project.git (fetch)
origin  git@git.assembla.com:project.git (push)
```

And checked branches too:

```
git branch -a
* master
  showcase
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/showcase
```

Fine.

And then I ran:

```
 git remote update
 Fetching origin
```

But running `git status` told me there was nothing to change. So I made another modification to the file and did a `git add filename` and `git commit -m "message blah"` but that returned:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Huh? Running `git log origin/master..HEAD` and `git log --stat origin/master..HEAD` returned nothing. Wha? I ran `git log -p` and it returned the last changes I had made a few weeks ago when git was still "working".

What do I do now? I've checked my git/config file and it looks good. I don't whant to trash everything, as I have unstaged changes that I want to keep. But they are effectively not logged and none of my cherry picked changes are getting registered. I'm stumped.

### Update

Following on from @joran's suggestion made me dig a bit deeper in the refs and I noticed that the last git push I made when it was 'working' (Jul 19), the commit had an SHA of `582e75966e93bd907311a0af7bba7d67af646684`. My log in GitX show this.

So I dug into my `.git/refs` folder and noticed that there's a difference between my remote and heads master files:

```
.git/refs/heads/master is 46ba1f4ce622bd37668ad31437db44906ca0d6be
```

Whereas

```
.git/refs/remotes/origin/master is 582e75966e93bd907311a0af7bba7d67af646684
```

Checking my repos on other projects I noticed that these two serials are normally the same. So I copy and pasted the remotes/origin/master's serial into the heads/master. GitX then showed me the last three files that I had been trying to modify and I committed them.

I then ran a `git push origin master` but hit on the same `everything up to date` message.

Looking closer at GitX shows that the "master" and "origin/master" are no longer associated as they are on my other functioning git projects:

Working repo: [image: local git works]

Dysfunctional repo: [image: local git not synced]

Comment: `git reflog`  may give some hints of how your local repo has changed (in the  case of missing commits)

Comment: @joran thanks for that. I ran the command and the last commit it displays was from 25 commits ago from March 2014. None from last month or yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

That seems really weird, I don't know what you missed here, but just in case, did you tried to `git clone` your repo in a fresh local directory ? Then making some changes and try to `add/commit/push` ? If it works, you should continue to working on it and manually re-do the changes you wanted to push originally.

Comment: Thanks @Rémi, I'm holding off on this "final solution" until I've exhausted other avenues.